# Django 1.11 'method' object is not subscriptable (Form / Model)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create an upload field where people can upload their CV/Resume. When I click on the 'submit' button I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/src/project/views.py", line 160, in careersView
    applicant_cv = applyModel(cv = request.FILES.get['cv'])
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

I am using the following config (Django 1.11, testing with the build-in webserver, debug enabled):

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class applyModel(models.Model) :
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to='cvs/')
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import applyModel

class applyForm(forms.Form) :
    name = forms.CharField(label="", required=True, max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Name', 'class': 'name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label="", required=True, max_length=100, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'E-mail Address', 'class': 'email'}))
    phone = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, max_length=20, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Phone Number', 'class': 'phone'}))
    linkedin = forms.CharField(label="", required=True, max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'LinkedIn / Professional Website', 'class': 'linkedin'}))
    portfolio = forms.CharField(label="", required=False, max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Portfolio', 'class': 'portfolio'}))
    hours = forms.CharField(label="", required=True, max_length=10, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Hours Available Per Week', 'class': 'hours'}))
    startDate = forms.CharField(label="", required=True, max_length=10, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Earliest Start Date', 'class': 'startDate'}))
    message = forms.CharField(label="", max_length=900, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Provide your motivation for this role (max five sentences)', 'class': 'message'}))
    position = forms.CharField(label="", max_length=900, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Message', 'class': 'position'}))
    cv = forms.FileField(label="Upload CV/Resume")
```

**Views.py**

```
from .forms import applyForm
from .models import applyModel


@csrf_exempt
def careersView(request):
    if request.method == "POST" :
        form = applyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            phone = request.POST.get("phone")
            linkedin = request.POST.get("linkedin")
            hours = request.POST.get("hours")
            startDate = request.POST.get("startDate")
            message = request.POST.get("message")
            position = request.POST.get("position")
            portfolio = request.POST.get("portfolio")
            applicant_cv = applyModel(cv = request.FILES.get['cv'])
            cv_filename = applyModel.objects.get()
            cv_filename = cv_filename.cv.name
            return render(request, '/careers/careers_template.html', {'form': form})
    else :
        form = applyForm()
    return render(request, '/careers/careers_template.html', {'form': form})
```

**Settings.py**

```
  I've added this template: 'django.template.context_processors.media',
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    And yes, I have the following line in my urls.conf: 
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**HTML File**

```
   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="closeBtn"><img src="{% static 'img/svgs/icon-close-sm-dark.svg'%}"/></div>
      <div class="icon">
        <img src=""/>
      </div>
      <h1>Application for: </br> </br> <span class="title"></span> <span class="hours"></span></h1>
      {{ form }}
      <input class="hvr-bob submitBtn" type="submit" name "contact" value="Send Message" />
      <div class="success">
        <p><svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52"><circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/><path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/></svg> </br> <span>Thank you for applying!</span>  </br> We will be in touch shortly.</p>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the method `get` with square brackets, try this instead:

```
applicant_cv = applyModel(cv = request.FILES.get('cv'))
```

Comment: I am not getting the error anymore, but the file is not saved in my media directory. When I press the submit button I get a HTTP 200 and no errors.

Comment: @ErikN - Did you resolve this? I have the same issue

Comment: Hey @DanWhite , yeah I was able to solve it, I know this may sound a bit strange, but it had something to do with the custom.js file. After I removed this fle (include) from my form page it worked. Maybe you could remove some of those JS files as well and then try if it works (custom.js is obviously for everyone different).